# MoPub Full SDK 3.0.0 Integration

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, automatic-ref-counting, integration, mopub

Regarding the new [MoPub iOS SDK 3.0.0](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/tree/3.0.0) and its [Getting Started](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started) documentation:

1. Download the MoPub SDK
2. Add the SDK to your Xcode project.
3. ...

During step 2, as Unity 3D generates MRC Xcode projects and the MoPub documentation says:

`If your application uses Manual Reference Counting (MRC) you must tell the compiler to build the MoPub iOS SDK source files with ARC.`

All SDK files had their compiler flags set to `-fobjc-arc`. Then two new issues appeared:

1. `"Cannot use '@try' with Objective-C exceptions disabled" Error` which was fixed by Enabling Objective-C Exceptions inside project's build settings; and
2. `'__weak' only applies to Objective-C object or block pointer types;` from file `MPStreamAdPlacer.m` (see attached screenshots).

[image: MoPubMRCIntegrationError1.jpg]
[image: MoPubMRCIntegrationError2.jpg]

As the documentation does not cover the above described issues, how can I fix these last compiling errors?

NOTE: Works fine with [MoPub iOS SDK 2.4.0](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/tree/2.4.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/issues/82

khchen428 said:

Thanks for reporting this issue! We'll have a fix out soon. In the mean time, here is a workaround:
In `MoPubSDK/Native Ads/MPStreamAdPlacer.m` starting at line 156:

replace:
`__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`
with:
`__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;`

and replace:
`typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;`
with:
`__typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;`

Comment: it's still not fixed in the current version

Answer (score 1):

I deleted lines:

```
__weak typeof(self) _weakSelf = self;
```

and

```
typeof(self) strongSelf = _weakSelf;
```

and replaced all references **strongSelf** by **self**

it works for me